# Django Application Lifecycle

Tags: python, django

What does exactly happen with Django application from request to response?

I've read some docs online from which what I get is as follows-
1> When an API gets called request come to url.py.
2> Before or after middleware comes in part to do pre/post operations on request.
3> Then request forward to views.py.
4> If any data serialization/deserialization then request data gets passed to serializers.py.
5> Whatever response generated returned through middleware again.

Comment: You somehow managed to write your own answer within your question.

Comment: Check the image in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579864/what-happens-in-a-simple-django-rest-framework-application-that-has-an-angular-f)